# Time Complexity of a weird loop

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science

What's the time complexity of this loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i *= 2)

   { //Something with O(1) complexity here }
```

I would guess O(log n*n).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yep your guess is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, as *i* doubles on each iteration and the loop terminates when *i >= n<sup>2</sup>*, making it run for *O(log n<sup>2</sup>)* iterations.

However, notice that *O(log n<sup>2</sup>) = O(2 log n) = O(log n)*.

EDIT: However, as Zilog80 points out, this piece of code initializes `i` as *0*, which will cause the loop to run for infinity since *0 * 2 = 0*. If you initialize it as some positive (constant) number, however, then your calculation is correct.

Comment: As the initialization of the `i` counter is 0, it's in fact an infinite loop. It seems the adequate notation doesn't exist, but it would be *O(∞)* or *O(0)* [meaning an unsolvable one, i guess the *O(∞)* is better]  ^^ Except indeed if the `i` is altered in some ways in the *O(1)* process but OP did not precise this.

Comment: @Zilog80 Oh look at that! Thanks, I'll update my answer.